# Add meta-viewport tag to header of OVH Redirection Technology page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frame

I have this issue when deploying an app.
My provider is OVH and for some reason the adopted mode of deployement uses an "invisible redirection" which puts the URL inside of a frame.

The end result is something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>espaceClient</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="generator" content="ORT - Ovh Redirect Technology">
        <meta name="url" content="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY">
        <meta name="robots" content="all">
    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%,0" frameborder=no border=0>
        <frame name="ORT" src="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY">
        <frame name="NONE" src="" scrolling="no" noresize>
        <noframes>
            <body><a href="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY">Click here</a><hr></body>
        </noframes>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

The design of the page is mobile-friendly and responsive, for some reason, the frame kills these aspects. In other words: the page displays on a mobile as if it were a desktop screen of a laptop.

After some more research, I understood that it would be necessary to add a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to this page, but the provider does not allow configuration of the page, hence I need to do it through javascript or jQuery.

I thought getting the parent document of the frame-document would do, but it does not:

```
var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');
viewPortTag.id="viewport";
viewPortTag.name = "viewport";
viewPortTag.content = "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;";
window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);
```

My question is the following: how could I make a script in the `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY` to append the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to the parent page as such:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>espaceClient</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="generator" content="ORT - Ovh Redirect Technology">
    <meta name="url" content="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY">
    <meta name="robots" content="all">
    <!-- added through some javascript written in  http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,0" frameborder=no border=0>
    <frame name="ORT" src="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY">
    <frame name="NONE" src="" scrolling="no" noresize>
    <noframes>
        <body><a href="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY">Click here</a><hr></body>
    </noframes>
</frameset>
```

Comment: wow... isn't this something from Jurrasic Park? Framesets? What about browsers support? Framesets are deprecated and not sure if they care about repsoniveness of the element.

Comment: Tell me about it, but this is how OVH apparently allow you to do invisible redirection lol...

Comment: And they did not even have the presence of mind of adding to it this meta tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: It's basically obsolete. I can´t use a system that makes my website unavailable on smartphones. I lost 1h trying to make it work....